# Encrypt timestamp in Nodejs and Decrypt in R shiny app

Tags: r, node.js, encryption, shiny

I have a website with Nodejs backend and React frontend. I'm trying to redirect users from the React app to R shiny app for visualization.

How am I handling user authentication:
As R shiny app's free version doesn't provide authentication functionality, i want to allow website users to visit the Shiny app only with link generated from the website containing a token within 12 hours of its generation.
Token is basically an encrypted value of current timestamp in nodejs. Below is the nodejs code snippet,

```
const current_date = Date.now();
const cipher_message = current.date.to_string();
const key = process.env.ENC_KEY;
const iv = process.env.ENC_IV;
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc',key,iv);
cipher.update(cipher_message,'utf-8','hex');
const token = cipher.final('hex');
```

And this above token is attached to Shiny app redirect url as token parameter. I'm facing hard time in finding the appropriate functions in R Shiny to decrypt the token to original timestamp. Below are my efforts till now,

```
aes <- AES(enc_key, mode='CBC', enc_iv)
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) //url params are stored in query variable
aes$decrypt(query[["token"]])
```

My probable solution should be above 3 lines, but I'm getting error in line 1 AES command that 'AES only supports 16, 24 and 32 byte keys'. But the enc_key and enc_iv are same from the nodejs backend configs which does AES encryption perfectly. Not sure what i'm missing.

Also if there is any other better way to connect react and shiny app with some kind of authentication, i will be happy to learn. Thanks in advance

Update 1:
Looks like the AES error was because AES was expecting Key and IV values in raw, updated code is,

```
aes <- AES(charToRaw(enc_key), mode='CBC', charToRaw(enc_iv))
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) //url params are stored in query variable
aes$decrypt(query[["token"]])
```

Now i'm facing difficulty with decrypt command. May be some kind of conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the way to successfully decrypt token in R shiny which was encrypted in Nodejs using AES algo. Here below is the decrypt code,

```
aes <- AES(charToRaw(enc_key), mode='CBC', charToRaw(enc_iv))
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) 
decrypted <- strsplit(aes$decrypt(hex2raw(query[["token"]])),'\003')[1][1]
```

Key takeaways are:

1. Token had to be converted from HEX format to raw format for AES algo in R
2. Remove trailing '\003' characters from the end of the string